# show content when hover

Tags: html, css

I need to change style if i hover on `media-body` `checkbox` should show up

```
.media-body ul:hover input[type="checkbox"]  {
    display: block;     
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="media-body">
    <ul>
        <li><a style="float:left;">{{inventory.manufacturer}} {{inventory.model}}</a>
        <li><input style="float:right; display: none;" type="checkbox" ng-model="inventory.checked" ng-checked="inventory.checked"></li><br/>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline CSS has higher priority then outline, so you're changes are applied but are still overridden by your inline styles.

The simplest trick to make it work could be to set `!important` to your css.

```
.media-body ul:hover input[type="checkbox"]  {
    display: block !important;     
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WgQT5/

Anyway the right way would be to put inline styles outside of HTML.

Moreover your HTML is not valid. It should be

```
<div class="media-body">
    <ul>
        <li><a style="float:left;">{{inventory.manufacturer}} {{inventory.model}}</a></li> <!-- </li> missing -->
        <li><input style="float:right; display: none;" type="checkbox" ng-model="inventory.checked" ng-checked="inventory.checked"/></li><!-- <br/> is invalid here  and slash at the and of input was missing-->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the inline style `float: right; display: none;` has higher priority than the style defined in CSS.

I would suggest to add a default style in CSS equivalent to the inline one and then override this one:

CSS:

```
.media-body ul input[type="checkbox"]  {
    float: right;
    display: none;
}

.media-body ul:hover input[type="checkbox"]  {
    display: block;     
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="media-body">
    <ul>
        <li><a style="float:left;">{{inventory.manufacturer}} {{inventory.model}}</a></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" ng-model="inventory.checked" ng-checked="inventory.checked"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Only add !important and greater than selector

```
.media-body ul:hover > li input[type="checkbox"]  {
 display: block !important;
 }
```

[LIve code](http://jsfiddle.net/UTDnA/1/)